# DB lock issue in android

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

The following error occured while downloading and extraction of image sets and then unfortunately closed popup appear. please help me

```
05-26 13:01:54.637: E/SQLiteLog(15753): (5) database is locked
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753): Failed to open database '/data/data/org.com.clipToonz/databases/clipToonz.db'.
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:634)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:320)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:294)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at org.com.clipToonz.dbUtilities.ImageSetHandler.getImageSetIDByNameAndParentID(ImageSetHandler.java:187)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at org.apache.cordova.plugin.ExtractPlugin$unZipTask.doInBackground(ExtractPlugin.java:145)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at org.apache.cordova.plugin.ExtractPlugin$unZipTask.doInBackground(ExtractPlugin.java:1)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-26 13:01:54.657: E/SQLiteDatabase(15753):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-26 13:01:54.657: W/dalvikvm(15753): threadid=26: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41760ba8)
```

The following code used for insert image details

```
     DB_PATH=Constants.KEY_DBPATH;      
     String myPath = DB_PATH;
     db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);      
     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
     values.put(KEY_NAME,imageset.getName());
     values.put(KEY_PARENTID,imageset.getParentID());
     values.put(KEY_ISDIRECTORY ,imageset.getIsDirectory());
     values.put(KEY_CATEGORYID, imageset.getCategoryID());
     values.put(KEY_IMAGESETNAME, imageset.getImagesetName());
     values.put(KEY_PRIMARYNAME, imageset.getPrimaryName());

    // String query = "INSERT INTO " +imageset.getTableName()+ "("+KEY_IMAGESETNAME+","+KEY_NAME+","+KEY_PARENTID+","+KEY_ISDIRECTORY+","+KEY_CATEGORYID+","+KEY_PRIMARYNAME+") VALUES('"+imageset.getImagesetName()+"','"+imageset.getName()+"',"+imageset.getParentID()+","+imageset.getIsDirectory()+","+imageset.getCategoryID()+",'"+imageset.getPrimaryName()+"')";
     //System.out.println(imageset.getTableName());
    // Inserting Row
     //db.execSQL(query);
     db.insert(imageset.getTableName(), null, values);
     db.close(); // Closing database connection
```

and to detect existing image details

```
int returnValue=0;
    //String num;
            DB_PATH=Constants.KEY_DBPATH;
            String name=imagesetp.getName();
            int categoryid = imagesetp.getCategoryID();             
            String myPath = DB_PATH;
         db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        String selectQuery="SELECT * FROM "+imagesetp.getTableName()+" WHERE "+KEY_NAME+"='"+String.valueOf(name)+"' AND parentid="+parentID+" AND categoryid ="+categoryid;
        System.out.println("selectQuery " + selectQuery);

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
        // try{
         if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount()!=0)             
             cursor.moveToFirst();           
            returnValue=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));

    // }

    // finally{
         //cursor.close();
        // db.close();
    // }
         cursor.close();
         db.close();
    return returnValue;
```

Comment: Can you post your code? This might be happen when you try to write a db which is opened in read mode.

Comment: what is read mode ? i'm new to this app.

Comment: Refer this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 0):

*As I am not able to write comments yet (50 reputation needed), I write here - but more than that this should be your answer:*

You **try to open the database while it is still in usage** at another line of code. To avoid inconsistence the database will automatically be locked for every other access, but this one. At first you have to allocate this resource (with db.close() - which seems to be missing somewhere at your code) before it can be used somewhere else.

Something more:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = new DataBaseHelper(context).getReadableDatabase();
```

and

```
SQLiteDatabase db = new DataBaseHelper(context).getWritableDatabase();
```

is the more common way to get your database.

---

**edit:**

I guess I found your bug. Please format your code next time - it will help you!

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount()!=0)             
             cursor.moveToFirst();           
            returnValue=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
```

This is where your database will not be closed before leaving the method! Your function will be left after return. Place a `db.close()` before this return.

Best regards
Vince